# How to get length of the fields which has duplicate values in firestore flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying get length of the fields which has duplicate values in firestore. I am using collectionGroup to fetch all data inside collection called report and displaying a field called email. if same email is repeating for 2 times then it should count 2 along side that email. I don't have any idea on it and don't know from where to start. I want to display it on scaffold widget.

Answer (score 0):

**Below code will find the duplicates from your array. Now modify it as your need:**

```
   void main() {
      List<Map<String, dynamic>> users = [
        { "name": 'John', 'email': 'a@b.c' },
        { "name": 'Jane', 'email': 'a@b.c' },
        { "name": 'Mary', 'email': 'a@b.c' },
        { "name": 'Mary', 'email': 'a@b.c' },
      ];
      List tempList = List();
      users.forEach((u){
        if (tempList.contains(u["email"])) print("duplicate ${u["email"]}");
        else names.add(u["name"]);
      });
    }
```